Problem implementing navigation after granting Permissions with MutableStateFlow
Hi guys I need help implementing some state stuff.
Basically, I'm using MainViewModel for managing permissions, and after clicking the "Request multiple permissions" button and granting every permission, I want to immediately navigate the user to the next screen.
I think my problem is that I am not properly collecting value from MutableStateFlow
    viewModel:
    private val _allPermissionsGranted = MutableStateFlow(false)
        val allPermissionsGranted = _allPermissionsGranted.asStateFlow()
    
    composable:
    val granted by viewModel.allPermissionsGranted.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = granted) {
            if (granted) {
                navigateToCamera()
            }
        }

More code:
    @HiltViewModel
    class MainViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    
        var permissionsToRequest = arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
        )
    
        private val permissionsMap = mutableMapOf(Pair(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, false))
    
        private val _allPermissionsGranted = MutableStateFlow(false)
        val allPermissionsGranted = _allPermissionsGranted.asStateFlow()
    
        fun onPermissionResult(
            permission: String, isGranted: Boolean
        ) {
            permissionsMap[permission] = isGranted
            val all = permissionsMap.values.all { it }
            Log.d("tag", "$all") // logging true value correctly 
            _allPermissionsGranted.value = all
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun Home(
        askForPermissions: () -> Unit,
        navigateToCamera: () -> Unit
    ) {
        val viewModel = hiltViewModel<MainViewModel>()
        val granted by viewModel.allPermissionsGranted.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = granted) {
            if (granted) {
                Log.d("tag", "$granted") // never logged anything
                navigateToCamera()
            }
        }
    
        Column() {
            Button(onClick = {
                askForPermissions()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Request multiple permissions")
            }
        }
    }


I think launchedEffect is in a new coroutine scope. Maybe removing launchedEffect and just do if(granted) will work. It's not clear what the navigateToCamera callback does, maybe that's the problem.

Your Log messages look identical. I suggest changing log msg to be sure you don't miss the one in composable.
